# kivy and extension .kv i am not understanding

Tags: python, kivy

I am developing a software with `kivy`.

Goal: I need to put several images on click on this project

At start I am trying with the `.kv` extension to do background and the 2 images on click, like the program below, but it is not working.

I don't understand, please help.

Extra: Let me know if you have some ideas to distribute several images with click, please help too.

#### .py:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.0')


from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior 
from kivy.uix.image import Image

Value1=6

Value2=10


class BackgroundBoxLayout(FloatLayout):
    pass

class ImageButton1(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    #pos = (2,2)
    def on_press(self):
        print (Value1)

class ImageButton2(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    #pos_hint: {"x": 500, "y":500}
    def on_press(self): 
        print (Value2)


class program(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    program().run()
```

#### .kv:

```
<program>:
    BackgroundBoxLayout:
    ImageButton1:
    ImageButton2:

<BackgroundBoxLayout>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

<ImageButton1>:
    BoxLayout:
        source: 'carrinhomini.jpg'
        size_hint_x: .20
        size_hint_y: .20
        #pos_hint: {'y':0, 'x': 1}

<ImageButton2>:
    BoxLayout:
        source: 'basketsemfundo1.png'
        size_hint_x: .20
        size_hint_y: .20
        #pos_hint: {'center_x':.3, 'center_y': .3}
        #pos_hint: {'y':0, 'x': 0}
```

Comment: Hi Rafael,  Welcome to the community.   Please provide any errors that you are getting from your code.  That will help the community be able to better assist you.

Comment: Hi JayRizzo, thanks to the answer.
The program open, but the screen is all black, like nothing works
if i take off the <> of all class and the FloatLayout, doing only the imagebuttons the program works fine

Comment: are you getting any output?  are you debugging your program?  any additional information that you have will assist others in understanding your issue.  screenshots help too at times.

Comment: i tried again drop printscreens, but i think i cant because i am new, but ok
i will try explain better:

In this program i need the background and the imagesbuttons

I even managed the three things, but just in the same class, like: 

BoxLayout:
 canvas:
  Color:
   rgba: 0, 1, 1, 1
  Rectangle:
   pos: self.pos
   size: self.size
 spacing: 2
    orientation:'vertical'
 
 #Label:
  #text: "Alo mundo- Aqui estou eu"
    
 ImageButton1:
        source: 'basketsemfundo1.png' ...... etc

Comment: Yes, I can understand the frustration.  I have never used `kivy` before but make sure to look at the docs https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/architecture.html  Maybe that will help until someone know can.  Cheers!

Comment: sry, i posted incomplet and edit, now i am completing hehe
continuing...
But with in the same class the spacing images doesnt work well, so i need diferent diferents classes....This point i stuck, because i am not understanding how diferent classes work with .kv

i see your answer. i will continue trying search in docs, but thanks for your time, thanks a lot buddy

Comment: One big problem is that your `class program(App)` is missing a `build()` method.

Comment: like:


class program(App):

    def build(self):

        return program
??

Comment: The `build()` method must return a `Widget`, but `program` is an `App`, not a `Widget`. There are many ways to handle this. One is to create another class, for example `class ProgramDisplay(BoxLayout)` and replace `<program>` in your `KV` with `<ProgramDisplay>`. Then your `build()` method could do `return ProgramDisplay()`.

Comment: Another problem I see is that in your `kv` file, the rules for `ImageButton1` and `ImageButton2` have a `BoxLayout:` line that I think is unnecessary. If you remove those lines, I think your `ImageButton1` and `ImageButton2` will be displayed.

Comment: John Anderson, after many tries, i got it! Thank you for your tips, without it i think i ll spend much more time.

And after your fast answers i ll join this community helping with i know>
Thank you again, John and Jay.